# Jfree chart version of jide soft line chart with gradient fill

Tags: jfreechart

I need to get the code that would help me create a chart similar to the one shown in the image http://www.jidesoft.com/images/line-chart-gradient-fill.png also it should be a time series chart

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to recommend to buy the JFreeChart developers guide. It contains a large set of good examples and it supports the maintainer of this project.

Regarding your question: I don't know what your main target is.

A good starting point is the class `TimeSeriesChartDemo1` provided with the JFreeChart sources.

Modify the `createChart` method of this demo by setting a different renderer:

```
    private static JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
        "Legal & General Unit Trust Prices",  // title
        "Date",             // x-axis label
        "Price Per Unit",   // y-axis label
        dataset,            // data
        true,               // create legend?
        true,               // generate tooltips?
        false               // generate URLs?
    );

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));
    plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
    plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);

    XYItemRenderer r = new XYAreaRenderer2();
    r.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(255, 0, 0, 50));
    r.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(0, 255, 0, 50));
    plot.setRenderer(r);

    DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy"));

    return chart;

}
```

Comment: Does that answer your question? In such a case please mark your question as resolved. Thanks!